Restoring/creating a new bootable partition for existing Windows 7 installation
I have an old Windows 7 installation that I wanted to transfer to a new PC since the system is already configured, Windows is activated and all of my files are on there.
I wanted to clone my 500GB HDD from my previous PC to the NVME inside the new PC, as to not void the warranty by simply opening the PC.
So I used an external HDD enclosure to attach the disk, hoping to boot into Windows and use Minitool Partition Wizard to migrate the OS, the only problem is that the Windows install is MBR, and for some reason, I can't turn on CSM or disable "Safe Mode" in the BIOS (it's an ASUS motherboard), the options are grayed out and unselectable.
I managed to use Minitool Partition Wizard on another PC to change the drive from MBR to GPT (as I've confirmed is needed to boot successfully through searching and a test install of Windows 10), booting into Ubuntu Live, I managed to clone the disk with ddrescue directly to the NVME, and now I can't boot from it because the system doesn't recognize it.
From looking at the partitions, I don't see an EFI partition, only the "System reserve", windows primary and separate storage partition.
Is there a way to rebuild the EFI partition for this Windows 7 PC, or is there something else I can do/am missing?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Ok, sounds like you've overcomplicated this quite a bit.
TL;DR: just start with a fresh install of Windows 11 on the new PC and transfer your documents from the old system by connecting the old HDD via the external enclosure. Don't mess with the old drive at all anymore - it's your only copy of your documents, so keep it as a backup.

First off, trying to transfer an entire Windows install from one PC to another is begging for issues, especially when the two machines don't have nearly identical hardware. I won't say you can't brute force your way through getting the old install to work on the new hardware, but I guarantee you it isn't worth the effort or the risk of losing all of your data altogether. Like others have mentioned, you're facing up against an impossible nightmare of driver incompatibility and even if you were able to get the system to boot on the new machine that way, the computer would always have all sorts of weird issues and crashes. Trying to upgrade the old machine to Windows 10 first won't change that either.
Second, because you've converted the old HDD from MBR to GPT, there's a good chance it won't boot even if you plug it back into the old machine. The way that Windows boots on the two filesystems differs, and the missing EFI partition means that the old machine probably won't recognize the GPT drive as a bootable device. DO NOT TRY TO FIX THAT! You'd be begging to lose all of the data on the drive, which as far as I can tell is your only copy of your files. Get the new PC set up with a fresh install, then connect the HDD as an external drive to copy your documents off. Once you're done, disconnect the HDD, put it in a drawer, and don't touch it unless you realize you forgot to copy something over.

Thank you for a constructive answer. The data itself is not the problem since I already would've backed up anything important, this whole thing is mostly about keeping Windows activated, the data  is just a bonus as it getting erased would only really be an inconvenience. I thought moving and upgrading windows would be plausible, since I've done so in the past with an "OEM System Builder Pack" for that laptop I mentioned in the comments above. I never really moved a live installation, certainly not across different drive architectures and technologies.

I do have two questions though:
1. Does then my theory hold true, that I could get a "Windows 7" or similar older licence and use it to activate Windows 10/11 since it would be cheaper and basically the same thing?
2. Is there some software that could automate this task of moving all of the applications from the old drive to the new (moving everything from "Program files" or Desktop on the old disk to the same place on the new one), or is that something I'd have to do manually?

I'll answer the first question myself, after a bit of Googling it turns out that Microsoft no longer allows users to activate Windows 10 with Windows 7/8 keys, so apparently that's no longer possible since I remember doing it in the past and that PC is still in use today.

AGAIN: Your Windows 7 is OEM. OEM licenses are NOT transferable. You would have been able to upgrade the OLD computer to Windows 10 with the same license. You can't use another computer's OEM license for that purpose, it WON'T activate even if still allowed to (it isn't, that ship sailed a long time ago).
